# One page, multiple contexts ? Is that possible?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my problem: I have an app that has 2 list view.builders. You can imagine the scenario.

within the Stateful widget, we have:

```
 Widget build(ct)
 {
```

and this returns a column widget that has TWO list views.

The problem I have is that one list view changes (or should change) the items in another list view.

So what are my options? To create two Widget build(ct1) and Widget build(ct2)??

Do we do that? How can I communicate changes to ct1?

Oh my goodness, I've tried a lot, even setState etc... nothing works.. Perhaps could someone tell me how I can invoke the page to be refreshed?? That would work.

Answer (score 0):

I keep on finding the answers myself - but for anyone who has this issue, Flutter apparently has evolved... if you are using the latest version, I really believe that SetState() function should work for you.. you just need to use it in the right place.